# Cannot push to rubygems.org

Tags: ruby, networking, rubygems

I cannot push my gem to rubygems, each time I do I get the same error:

```
$ gem push mygemnamehere-0.1.0.gem
Pushing gem to https://rubygems.org'...
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (SocketError)
    Failed to open TCP connection to rubygems.org':443 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
```

I have tried the following:

- `gem update --system`
- Editing my ~/.gemrc preferences to switch to http (from https)
- Removing the part of my .gemspec that locks pushing to https://rubygems.org
- Disabling IPv6 on both wired and wireless connections
- Disabling either connection
- On and off VPN
- Switched ISP (directly wired, wi-fi to wired, and phone-as-hotspot) with other connections disabled
- Adding an IPv4 IP to my hosts to lock the IP address

None of them changed the error message. I can curl https://rubygems.org and visit it in a browser.

```
$ curl -4 -v --head https://rubygems.org
*   Trying 151.101.192.70...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to rubygems.org (151.101.192.70) port 443 (#0)
...
```

How could it be that no else [has ever](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22Failed%20to%20open%20TCP%20connection%20to%20rubygems.org:443%20(getaddrinfo:%20nodename%20nor%20servname%20provided,%20or%20not%20known)%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) encountered this issue before? I must be missing something obvious. Help!

Comment: Did you try `rake release` command?

Comment: I ran into rubygems.org issue recently. I figured out it was hotspot issue https://amitpatel.xyz/digging-into-could-not-fetch-specs-from-https-rubygems-org-error/

Comment: This comes up a lot on SO and it's always a network configuration issue. ALWAYS. I'm going to guess you have something like Little Snitch installed that is blocking it silently.

Comment: @MasafumiOkura I don't understand why, but `rake release` worked. If you post this as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you!